# How to convert a table object into a matrix using R

Tags: r, list, matrix, frequency

I have a list X of length 2, which the first consists of 21 vectors of different length and the second of 24 vectors of different lengths, as follow:

```
>X
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
 [1]  56  66  67  76  86  96  97  98  88  78  79  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  69  59  60  58  68  57  70

[[1]][[2]]
 [1]  56  66  67  76  86  96  97  98  88  78  79  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  69  59  60  58  68  57  70  48

[[1]][[3]]
 [1]  48  58  59  60  69  79  78  88  98  97  96  86  76  66  67  56  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  68  57  70  95

[[1]][[4]]
 [1]  95  96  86  97  76  66  67  56  98  88  78  79  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  69  59  60  58  68  57  70  55

[[1]][[5]]
 [1]  55  56  66  67  76  86  96  97  98  88  78  79  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  69  59  60  58  68  57  70  49

[[1]][[6]]
 [1]  49  59  60  58  69  79  78  88  98  97  96  86  76  66  67  56  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  68  57  70  47

[[1]][[7]]
 [1]  47  57  56  66  67  76  86  96  97  58  98  88  78  79  77  59  60  87  89  99 100  90  80  69  68  70  50

[[1]][[8]]
 [1]  50  60  59  58  69  79  78  88  98  97  96  86  76  66  67  56  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  68  57  70  75

[[1]][[9]]
 [1]  75  76  66  86  96  67  56  97  98  88  78  79  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  69  59  60  58  68  57  70  85

[[1]][[10]]
 [1]  85  86  96  97  76  66  67  56  98  88  78  79  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  69  59  60  58  68  57  70  65

[[1]][[11]]
 [1]  65  66  56  67  76  86  96  97  98  88  78  79  77  87  89  99 100  90  80  69  59  60  58  68  57  70  46

[[1]][[12]]
[1] 12 22 32 23 24 13 14 34 33

[[1]][[13]]
 [1] 12 22 32 23 24 13 14 34 33 11

[[1]][[14]]
 [1] 11 12 22 32 23 24 13 14 34 33  2

[[1]][[15]]
 [1]  2 12 22 32 23 24 13 14 34 33  3

[[1]][[16]]
 [1]  3 13 23 24 22 32 12 14 34 33  4

[[1]][[17]]
 [1]  4 14 24 23 22 32 12 13 34 33 42

[[1]][[18]]
 [1] 42 32 22 23 24 12 13 14 34 33 35

[[1]][[19]]
 [1] 35 34 24 23 22 32 12 13 14 33 25

[[1]][[20]]
 [1] 25 24 23 22 32 12 13 14 34 33 21

[[1]][[21]]
 [1] 21 22 32 23 24 12 13 14 34 33 31


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
 [1]  56  57  58  59  69  70  79  78  88  98  99 100  77  76  80  67  87  68  89  66  86  96  90  60  97

[[2]][[2]]
 [1]  56  57  58  59  69  70  79  78  88  98  99 100  77  76  80  67  87  68  89  66  86  96  90  60  97  46

[[2]][[3]]
 [1]  46  56  57  58  59  69  70  79  78  88  98  99 100  77  76  80  67  87  68  89  66  86  96  90  60  97  55

[[2]][[4]]
 [1]  55  56  57  58  59  69  70  79  78  88  98  99 100  77  76  80  67  87  68  89  66  86  96  90  60  97  47

[[2]][[5]]
 [1]  47  57  56  58  59  69  70  79  78  88  98  99 100  77  76  80  67  87  68  89  66  86  96  90  60  97  75

[[2]][[6]]
 [1]  75  76  77  78  88  98  99 100  79  69  70  59  58  57  56  80  67  87  68  89  66  86  96  90  60  97  48

[[2]][[7]]
 [1]  48  58  57  56  59  69  70  79  78  88  98  99 100  77  76  80  67  87  68  89  66  86  96  90  60  97  85

[[2]][[8]]
 [1]  85  86  76  77  78  88  98  99 100  96  79  69  70  59  80  58  57  56  67  87  68  89  66  90  60  97  95

[[2]][[9]]
 [1]  95  96  86  76  77  78  88  98  99 100  79  69  70  59  80  58  57  56  67  87  68  89  66  90  60  97  50

[[2]][[10]]
 [1]  50  60  70  69  59  79  78  88  98  99 100  77  76  80  58  57  56  67  87  68  89  66  86  96  90  97  65

[[2]][[11]]
 [1]  65  66  56  57  76  77  78  88  98  99 100  79  69  70  59  80  58  67  87  68  89  86  96  90  60  97  49

[[2]][[12]]
[1] 12 22 23 24 13 34 33 32 14

[[2]][[13]]
 [1] 12 22 23 24 13 34 33 32 14 42

[[2]][[14]]
 [1] 42 32 22 23 24 13 34 33 14 12 31

[[2]][[15]]
 [1] 31 32 22 23 24 13 34 33 14 12  4

[[2]][[16]]
 [1]  4 14 24 23 22 13 34 33 32 12  3

[[2]][[17]]
 [1]  3 13 23 24 22 34 33 32 14 12 21

[[2]][[18]]
 [1] 21 22 23 24 13 34 33 32 14 12 15

[[2]][[19]]
 [1] 15 14 24 23 22 13 34 33 32 12 11

[[2]][[20]]
 [1] 11 12 22 23 24 13 34 33 32 14 43

[[2]][[21]]
 [1] 43 33 23 24 22 13 34 32 14 12  2

[[2]][[22]]
 [1]  2 12 22 23 24 13 34 33 32 14 25

[[2]][[23]]
 [1] 25 24 23 22 13 34 33 32 14 12 44

[[2]][[24]]
 [1] 44 34 24 23 22 13 33 32 14 12 35
```

Now, what I need is to create 24 matrices of dimension 10x10 with the frequences (filled by row) of the values contained respectively in the first vectors of the two elements of the list X, that is `X[[1]][[1]]` and `X[[2]][[1]]`, in the second, in the third,... until the 24th.

For example the first matrix should be like this:

```
>Matrix1
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    2    2    2     2
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    2    2    2     2
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    2    2    2     2
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    2    2    2     2
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    2    2    2     2
```

Obviously, from the 22nd to the 24th it will calculate only the frequences of the values of the secondo element of the list, because the first element of the list X is of length 21.

I tried to use table, but then when I make `matrix(table(Matrix1))` it is not able to put it on a matrix of dimension 10x10 and to fill the zeros where needed.

I hope I have explaned exhaustively the problem. Anyone may suggest me please how could I do that?

Comment: add the "ncol=" argument in the matrix() call and try.

Comment: share a smaller sample for better understanding...